# AOSP 8.1 - minimum volume is too high

Tags: android-source, android-8.1-oreo

I have AOSP 8.1 and I would like to know if there is some possibility to change the behavior of the volume control (e.g. by modifying **build.props**, **Framework**/**SystemUI config**, ...).

Volume control in apps, which can override the system volume (like PowerAMP), behaves normally. For example, you can set their volume to values between 0 - 10%.

However, without **Precise Volume app**, the system **volume can be set only to 0% or more than 70%**. When I set volume steps to 50, all 50 steps are situated between 70 - 100%.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not include "thank you" or similar in your questions. See here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts